# Multitasking : How do I maintain the opera browser tabs keep active when switching applications

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, multitasking, opera-mini

Case:

When I was opening multiple pages/tabs on opera browser, then I press the home button to switch apps to see SMS, then i return to the opera app by holding the home button, suddenly my tabs open is missing, such as the open new. Anyone know how to maintain the opera browser tabs keep active as they move another application?

My Phone Info

Model number: Device-01,
Android Version: 2.3.6, baseband version: VENUS_BP_00.03.63.b501, Kernel Version: 2.6.38.6-perf zly @ HL120 # 1.

Thank you.

Comment: Opera Mini or Opera Mobile? I have no issues with Opera Mobile. I have a Samsung Galaxy S2, running CM10.1

Comment: @geffchang: iam using Opera Mini 7.5

Comment: Is your Developer Options enabled?

Comment: @geffchang : No. I turn off all.

Comment: No issues with Opera Mini here. Probably and issue with your phone's ROM; can't help you there. Hopefully somebody else can help you.

Comment: Using task-killers? Simple answer is **Dont use one** and let android manage memory for you.

Comment: @forums : Yes i using task-killers. But i cant removed it. This application has been installed as the default application android phone. Uninstall button like "disabled".

Comment: @geffchang : I was trying to delete some of the system apps but there was no option say "delete" or "uninstall"? i update my phone info above.

Comment: @forums : Hi, I've managed to root my phone and remove Task Killer app. Apparently it the application is causing my phone multitask disturbed. Thanks for the info. Now my phone gt better.. :)

Comment: ^ great, now just make an answer with the steps that you did to solve the problem and accept it :D

Comment: Hi, it's been a long time, but looks like you found the solution. Would you post a self-answer to consider this question solved? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just do the following:

1. go to settings.
2. then go inside developer options
3. then go to the app section. There you find option saying "don't keep activities". Put it OFF...thats it.
4. now browse opera mini on phone...it will sort out your problem.

Now you can tab between multiple tasks – and no need to worry about anything. It works for me too. I have a KitKat version.

Answer (score 0):

Multitasking is truly supported by devices with higher end chip configuration( i.e.good clocking speed 1Ghz and or sufficient RAM>=500Mb ).

In simple terms is that insufficient ram will not be able to hold more then one application at the same time and less processor speed will take some time to load in app data for both the applications(although i think RAM is the main area to be concentrated for your multitasking purpose)

Due to limited resource the kernel has to decide which task to be given more priority either task 1 or task2.Based on it's decisions only the browser is temporarily shut and the message is loaded.Later when you load the browser back the kernel gives this as higher priority and it loads the browser back.(If you have  multiple number of tabs with heavy activity going simultaneously then you have to decide which is of least importance and close the tab.)

**Ex**-:Say you have opened up to 4 tabs named Tab1-Tab4.

Tab1-Email

Tab2-Browse Video

Tab3-Download content

Tab4-Social networking

As you can see all are processor demanding tabs and will not work all at the same time.
So if you opened Tab2(browse video) and later switched to Tab4(Social networking). The browser will reload Tab4 due to higher inactivity on this tab and not close it.

Same goes with the switching between two different applications.The browser will load the page but not close the tab.
What i can suggest you is that either you use less no of tabs in the browser and then shift to any other application.(Clearing the cache memory may also resolve the issue)

**Note**:-If at all you still feel that there are only 2 tabs and still the browser has crashed/closed the tabs while in-app/switching through 2 different apps then you need  to contact the support team of the respective browser.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to stop android from destroying activities on its own.

Go to setting, Developer Options and then to the bottom. You will find two options over there (among the many) that are useful.

First is the 'Destroy activities as soon as the user leaves them' checkbox. Uncheck it.

Then go to the 'BackGround Process Limit' and set it to standard. This much should be enough....

Comment: Android will still destroy activities when low on resources, regardless of whether this developer option is disabled, which it is by default.